# tuxad-php repo problem

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, ssl

I try to update PHP with the tuxad-php repo as I need TLS 1.2 support which centos 5 doesn't offer. Upgrading the linux version is not currently feasible.

I run into a dependency problem with php-api, which blocks the upgrade and yum doesn't really have a 'force' option. --skip-broken doesn't seem to work. I get this:

```
--> Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed.
```

Normally in this situation I just download the rpm files from the repo manually, but with tuxad I can't seem to find the urls so I can't download the rpms directly. Because of the dependency problem yum -downloadonly doesn't download either.

Can you help me with this? with `rpm -Uvh` I can use a force command to ignore dependencies. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

found it.

the tuxad.com blog has a link to an rpm, and taking it from there I get

https://www.tuxad.com/repo/5/i386/tuxad-php/php-5.3.3-49.1.el5_11.i386.rpm

yum will give the exact filenames (minus the .rpm bit) that you can add to the rest of the url. Wget does the rest.

i had to `force deinstall' php-mcrypt though to get rid of errors related to the php-api dependency. Now phpmyadmin might not work anymore (as it's dependent on that lib), but i didn't use that so much anyways... oh well, stuff...